# Java HTML Editor Kit that supports Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, swing, browser

I am writing code for a mini desktop browser. I am using a JEditorPane to display the webpage on the application. The problem I have is that this JEditorPane does not have javascript support. I heard that I can implement javascript support with HTML Editor Kit. Please could someone tell me how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Check [Lobo browser](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp) which is written in Java. It has a [BrowserPanel](http://lobobrowser.org/platform-api/org/lobobrowser/gui/BrowserPanel.html) component which can be used in any Swing application.

Comment: Is it the BrowserPanel that makes it able to support Javascript?

Comment: Yes the Lobo browser (BrowserPanel) supports Javascript.

Comment: If I put the Browser Panel on my swing application, would javascript be supported?